# Keystore does not work on Java 9

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, java-9

I've converted a JKS keystore to the P12 format using portecle, but it probably didn't go well. The keystore works with Java 8 (various versions), but with Java 9 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode), I'm getting

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(java.base@9-internal/JavaKeyStore.java:659)
        at sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(java.base@9-internal/KeyStoreDelegator.java:219)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(java.base@9-internal/KeyStore.java:1466)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:998)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:219)
```

The funny thing is that Java 8 keytool shows

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 5 entries
... entries listed
```

while the one from Java 9 shows

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 5 entries
... entries listed
```

I'm aware of [JEP 229](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229) and I've read the related issues, but I can't see any related problem.

Comment: Wait. Java 9 JRE or compiled against Java 9 JDK?

Comment: @Michael Compiled on Java 8 (same JAR used in all tests), ran on various machines (Java 8 and 9).

Comment: The Java8 `Keystore` type `JKS` can read both JKS AND PKCS12 since 8u60 in 2015 -- [see the release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u60-relnotes-2620227.html) at 'Keystore Compatibility Mode' near the bottom. Your program (or its config) probably specifies type JKS, which in 8 can read PKCS12 but in 9 cannot. keytool in 8 specifies type JKS which can read it, and keytool in 9 specifies type PKCS12 which can read it.

Answer (score 4):

The JDK keytool utility can convert a JKS keystore into a PKCS12 keystore.
For example, using JDK 9,

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ks.jks -destkeystore ks.p12
```

Also, there have been several keystore enhancements since 2016 so you should use a more recent release of JDK 9, see http://jdk.java.net/9/